# I have some trouble understanding things in my ER diagram

Tags: entity-relationship

I recently had an analysis exam and one part of the document contains an entity relation diagram. I got a response from the professor (who is now unavailable for questions) with some remarks. Most of them are from the ER diagram.

I'm not the best at making these diagrams and I have some problems understanding what needs to be done better.

This is the ER diagram that I have submitted:
[image]

A rough explanation:
A client has a problem with an electronic part that he bought in the store. With that part, he can go to the after sales service to get an estimate and have it repaired.

Steps:
The client goes to the reception 
The receptionist creates the client in the system and creates a ticket 
The ticket goes to the technicians 
The technician looks at it and creates an estimate 
If the client accepts they proceed with the repair 
the client goes back to the reception and pays

The remarks I got are the following:

- There are some N to N relationships and needs to be corrected using normal forms
- Employee is not an entity, but a role among others.
- How do we know what articles are on the invoice and estimate and how many
- Is the invoice price always the same as the estimate price?

**For the first point**, the only N,N relation that I have is between Person and Address. For me, a person can have 1 or many addresses and an address can have 1 or many persons. I don't know how I can correct this to not have an N,N relation

**For the second** I'm not quite sure why employee is a role. In my role entity I would have "technician, receptionist, admin, manager"

**For the 3rd and 4th** point I guess I'll just add: 
In invoice: 
Article 
Quantity 
Invoice Price

In estimate: 
Article 
Quantity 
estimate price

Could anyone help me understand this better?
If there is anything that I didn't mention please ask.
Thank you